# Too high frequency when building an LC circuit

Tags: passive-networks, resonance, troubleshooting

I am trying to build an LC oscillator for a thesis at my university. I'm aiming for ~3.5 MHz, I would a Helmholz pair with 30 windings each coil and a radius of 1.5 cm, which I calculated to have about 0.16 mH. I'm using a capacitance of 12 pF in parallel with the circuit. so this should give me:
\$f = 1/\sqrt{LC}/2\pi = 3.6\; \$MHz. All I see is on my VNA is a resonance at ~40 MHz.

I added a tuneable capacitance (50-200 pF) instead of the 12 pF one, and when tuning all the resonance does is broadening until gone, the frequency is still at ~40 MHz.

Anyone has a clue what is going on?

Comment: Should your title be "Too high ..."? **too** *adverb* - to an excessive degree.

Comment: We here *like* schematics...but yours makes no sense. Is your VNA *really* an AC voltage source? That's not how you excite a parallel LC resonator.

Answer (score 2):

Helmholtz coil has also big self capacitance, so you could measure the self resonance. FUrther if two of them are connected in series you also different situation as you would use a single coil. Perhaps you turned them to cancel each other, then you got such high frequency.

> which I calculated to have about 0.16 mH

But you have to measure it.